# Problems with multiline captions

Tags: jssor

How can I get multiline captions on my banner slider (standard)?

I was able to get the Banner Slider working in my custom Foundation HTML site, but the captions only show up as a single line and cut off anything after that first line.  Any ideas how to get multiline captions working?

Thanks!

```
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="https://fakeimg.pl/980x380/" />
            <div u="thumb">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add new line `<br/>`

```
    <div>
        <img data-u="image" src="https://fakeimg.pl/980x380/" />
        <div u="thumb">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br/> consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
```